# Endeca deployment - Initialize service.bat command failed

Tags: endeca

*Please find the error when I run the initialize_services command in cmd*

```
SEVERE: Caught an exception while invoking method 'run' on object 'InitialSetup'. Releasing locks.

Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke0 - null
Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.AppControlException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script runBeanShellScript - Unknown error executing a BeanShell script.
Caused by bsh.EvalError
bsh.BSHMethodInvocation eval - Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``             IFCR.provisionSite();     CAS.importDimensionValueIdMappings("Disco . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method importDimensionValueIdMappings( java.lang.String, java.lang.String ) not found in class'com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.component.CustomComponent'

Failure to initialize EAC application.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://mandarshinde.com/error-method-invocation-method-importdimensionvalueidmappings/) adding casStubs.jar from CAS_ROOT\lib\cas-dt\ to classpath in runcommand script will solve the problem.

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Endeca\CAS\11.1.0\lib\cas-dt\casStubs.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Will check and revert back.